# What does PRIM_MILES and COUNTYP010 stand for?

Tags: shapefile, metadata

I've downloaded the county boundaries (1 million scale) from this link: http://nationalmap.gov/small_scale/atlasftp.html?openChapters=chpbound#chpbound

A sample of the attributes in the dataset is:

ADMIN_NAME, ADMIN_FIPS, STATE, STATE_FIPS, NAME, SUFFIX, POP, SQ_MILES, PRIM_MILES, COUNTYP010

Autauga County, 01001, AL, 01, Autauga, County, 54571, 604.34339441800, 128.60014115400, 2678.00000000000

Barbour County, 01005, AL, 01, Barbour, County, 16589, 904.04255580000, 155.32318914800, 2760.00000000000

All of the attribute names I understand, except for PRIM_MILES and COUNTYP010. My research hasn't been able to turn up a description. Any ideas?

Comment: The dataset comes with metadata (.xml), which states that Countyp010 is `Internal feature number` and Prim_miles is `The perimeter of the county or county equivalent in miles.` The same information is in the .txt

Comment: @Vince Thanks for pointing out such an obvious blunder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from Vince's answer, there is a document that describes each of the files, which is actually linked off the page you referred to at http://nationalmap.gov/small_scale/atlasftp.html?openChapters=chpbound#chpbound

The third column says "Current Documentation Release" and has links labeled with dates. The link for County Boundaries goes to https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/53d103a1e4b004ac2f553b67 which provides a range of information - the part you are looking for is under "Attached Files" where you can get the metadata - view or download.

The Entity and Attribute information is part of the way down, where you'll get the same basic information as Vince showed:

```
 Attribute:

    Attribute Label: Prim_miles
    Attribute Definition:

        The perimeter of the county or county equivalent in miles.  This is a calculated field.

    Attribute Definition Source:
        National Atlas of the United States
    Attribute Domain Values:

        Range Domain:

            Range Domain Minimum: 6.4
            Range Domain Maximum: 4337.6

Attribute:

    Attribute Label: Countyp010
    Attribute Definition:

        Internal feature number.

    Attribute Definition Source:
        National Atlas of the United States
    Attribute Domain Values:

        Range Domain:

            Range Domain Minimum: 1
            Range Domain Maximum: 3642
```